# PHP ошибки с кодировкой

Tags: php, кодировка, unicode

Загружаю json данные со стороннего сайта, некоторые символы приходят в UNICOD (точнее переменные в JSON) примерно таком:

```
\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0431\u043e\u043b
```

Для преобразования входящих данных использую json_decode
Затем вывожу в дамп

```
$aa = json_decode('{"id":1,"name":"\u0412\u043e\u043b\u0435\u0439\u0431\u043e\u043b.\u00a0\u041a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u0445\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d.\u00a0\u041d\u0430\u0446\u0438\u043e\u043d\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0430\u044f\u00a0\u043b\u0438\u0433\u0430"}', true);
var_dump('Волейбол. Казахстан. Национальная лига');
var_dump($aa['name']);
```

Верхняя строка c var_dump **скопирована** с сайта!

В браузере получаю следующее

```
test.php:23:string 'Волейбол. Казахстан. Национальная лига' (length=71)
test.php:24:string 'Волейбол. Казахстан. Национальная лига' (length=74)
```

Мне интересно почему они имею **разную длину**. Потому что из-за этого, используя данные из нижнего var_dump, я не могу получить данные из БД. И каким способом это решить?
Версия PHP 5.6

Comment: ну так json сюда бы и вставили, воспроизведите проблему

Comment: @Jean-Claude Добавил в вопросе

Comment: У вас в одной строке обычные пробелы `\u20`, а в другой неразрывные `\u00a0`. Пробелов в строке как раз 3, вот и длина на 3 отличается. Хотя, по видимому, дело даже не в этом, поскольку `\u00a0` и `\ua0` одно и то же, то есть проблема в том, что PHP не нормализует UTF-8. Тем не менее, при нормализации будет одинаковая длина, а символы все равно разные. То есть, из базы по этой строке вы так ничего и не выберете.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov решение насильно заменять одни пробелы на другие? Т.е. в том формате который мне нужен

Comment: Да. Я, кстати, немного ошибся в комментарии. Символ `\u00a0` не попадает в ASCII, то есть в UTF-8 будет представлен двумя байтами. PHP тут не виноват.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov `$a = str_replace("\u00a0", " ", $a);` Использую такой костыль к входящим данным, и все отлично работает. Спасибо !

Comment: @AlexanderZonov оформили бы вы в виде ответа что ли. Столько вопросов без ответов на сайте((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было подсказано в комментариях.
Проблема в символе пробела, в возвращаемых данных есть символ `\u00a0`, который разница с обычным пробелом " ", пришлось вручную заменять изначально этот символ, придумал такое решение

```
$aa = str_replace("\u00a0", " ", $aa);
```

А затем уже декодировать остальные символы

```
$aa = json_decode($aa, true);
```